# Merge two arrays of hashes whilst keeping all distinct values

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, merge

I want to merge two arrays of hashes into a new array:

```
array1 = [{"Name1" => {gender: 'female', nationality: ['german', 'danish']}}]
array2 = [{"Name1" => {gender: 'male', nationality: ['german', 'austrian']}}]
```

Now this is the result I am looking for:

```
new_array = [{"Name1" => {gender: ['female', 'male'], nationality: ['german', 'danish', 'austrian']}}]
```

The only merge options I could find in the Ruby documentation would overwrite duplicates with the other hash. So how can I achieve the version I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass optional block argument to [`Hash#merge`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-merge). The block is invoked for the duplicated keys. in The return value of the block is used instead of being overwritten.

```
array1 = [{"Name1" => {gender: 'female', nationality: ['german', 'danish']}}]
array2 = [{"Name1" => {gender: 'male', nationality: ['german', 'austrian']}}]

new_array = [{'Name1' => array1[0]['Name1'].merge(array2[0]['Name1']) { |k,o,n|
  Array(o) | Array(n)
}}]
# => [{"Name1"=>
#       {:gender=>["female", "male"],
#        :nationality=>["german", "danish", "austrian"]}}]
```

Comment: `Array(o)` turns o into [o] and keeps [o] just [o]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How would you put together that operation if you were to fetch the hash_key ('Name1') instead of hardcode it? I need to loop through them rather than putting each of in manually.

Comment: @steenslag, Thank you for the comment. I updated the answer to use `Array` function.

Comment: @Severin, Use another `merge` call that merge `array1[0]` and `array2[0]`: `new_array = [
  array1[0].merge(array2[0]) { |k,o,n|
    o.merge(n) { |k,o,n|
      Array(o) | Array(n)
    }
  }
]`

Answer (score 1):

Recursive way :

```
array1 = [{"Name1" => {gender: 'female', nationality: ['german', 'danish']}}]
array2 = [{"Name1" => {gender: 'male', nationality: ['german', 'austrian']}}]

def merge_recur(ar1,ar2)
  (ar1+ar2).inject do |h1,h2|
    h1.merge(h2) do |k,o,n|
      if o.is_a?(Hash) and n.is_a?(Hash)
        merge_recur([o],[n])
      elsif o.is_a?(Array) and n.is_a?(Array)
        o | n
      else
        [o,n]
      end
    end
  end
end

merge_recur(array1,array2)
# => {"Name1"=>
#      {:gender=>["female", "male"],
#       :nationality=>["german", "danish", "austrian"]}}
```